# Writing an image file from array of xyz coordinate

Tags: c#, image, fractals

I'm currently working on a fractal generator in C# and I'm trying to export my set of coordinates to a very simple image file.

What i have is a 1-dimensional array of 3d point (x, y and z coordinate) and i wish to save it to an image where the z value will be the color of the pixel (grayscale only).

From what i gathered, the RAW format would be the easiest to work with, but even then i couldn't find documentation on it. I then looked at the namespace System.Drawing but i'm at a lost, it seems overly complicated for what i'm trying to achieve.

Is there an easy way to write such an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link should help explain how to create an image pixel by pixel:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

then you should be able to use image1.Save with a string argument of the file location.

If you just want to display it on a winform, then you could keep the original source code from the link.

You can create a new image instead of loading one like so:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap myMap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(200,300); //200x300 pixels
```